# How to rewrite array from row-order to column-order?

Tags: c++, c

I have this double for-loop, where I have both row-order and column-order array indexing, which should be bad for performance.

```
  for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {

      /* Column-major order */
      d = array_a[col*height +row];

      if (d < 0) { d = 0; }

      /* Row-major order */
      /* Map from x=0,y=0 at buttom left corner to
         0,0 at top left corner */
      array_b[width*(height-1 -row) + col] = d;

    }
  }
```

Is there an approach/method on how to rewrite from one to the other?

When I try to rewrite the last to column-order, the data becomes skewed. Can't it be rewritten?

Sandra

Comment: An easy solution is to write an array class that understands the concept. The just call switch row order. The underlying data does not need to be moved, the interface then just swaps the access parameters.

Comment: @Martin: boost::multi_array already supports this. Why does everyone ignore that wonderful library??? Not Invented Here syndrome? :-)

Comment: @Emile: Obviously use the correct tool in production code. But this is not a question about libraries. It is a question about techniques and code agility. The OP is obviously trying to understand some of the more basic concepts of the language not trying to understand the whole plethera of available libraries.

Comment: @Martin: I see your point. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is never going to be very fast as you'll probably have a number of cache misses, you'll either have to step to the one matrix with a large pitch or the other, there's no escaping that. The problem here is that a computer likes successive memory accesses to be close together, which in your algorithm is not the case the indexing of array_a skips by height elements at a time due to the `col*height` term. To fix that you could switch around the for loops, but then you'd have the same problem with the `width*(height-1 -row)` term in `array_b`.

You could rewrite one of the arrays to match the ordering of the other, but then you would have the exact same problem in the code which does the rewrite, so it depends on whether you need to do this kind of thing more than once on the same data, if you do, then it makes sense to first rewrite one of the matrices like Poita_ described, otherwise you'd best leave the algorithm as is.

Comment: if you ignore the constants in bigO complexity, then just store 2 matrices: the main one and its transpose. Then, use the one that's suitable for row access (i.e., the transpose if you asked for a column).

Answer (score 11):

Since the question is tagged C++, I'll contribute an answer that shows how accessing / manipulating column-major matrices can be done using [Boost.Multiarray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html) (it may be useful to others who face a similar problem). I consider Boost to be an extension to the C++ standard library. Feel free to ignore this answer if you don't like/use Boost. :-)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>

// Prints the contents of a matrix to standard output
template <class M> void printMatrix(const M& matrix)
{
    int height = matrix.shape()[0];
    int width = matrix.shape()[1];
    for (int row=0; row<height; ++row)
    {
        for (int col=0; col<width; ++col)
        {
            std::cout << matrix[row][col] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Source matrix data is in column-major format in memory,
    // with data starting at bottom-left corner.
    double data[] =
    {
        3, 7, 11,
        2, 6, 10,
        1, 5, 9,
        0, 4, 8
    };
    int width=4, height=3;

    // Store rows, then columns (column-major)
    int ordering[] = {0,1};

    // Store rows in descending order (flips Y axis)
    bool ascending[] = {true,false};

    // Create a multi_array that references the existing data,
    // with custom storage specifications.
    typedef boost::multi_array_ref<double, 2> Matrix;
    typedef boost::general_storage_order<2> Storage;
    Matrix matrix(
        data,
        boost::extents[height][width],
        Storage(ordering, ascending)
    );

    // Access source data as if it's row major
    printMatrix(matrix);
    std::cout << "\n";

    // Transpose source data to an actual row-major matrix
    // boost::multi_array is row-major by default
    boost::multi_array<double, 2> matrix2(boost::extents[height][width]);
    std::copy(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), matrix2.begin());
    printMatrix(matrix2);
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11

0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11
```

As you can see, you can leave the source data in its column-major format, and use `boost::multi_array_ref` with custom storage specifications to manipulate the data directly (as if it were row-major) using the `matrix[row][col]` notation.

If the matrix is going to be traversed often in row-major fashion, then it might be better to transpose it to an actual row-major matrix, as shown in the last part of my example.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been searching for. I came to this S-O page a few times and didn't see this answer because it was towards the bottom of the page. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

So you want to switch from something like:

```
0  1  2  3
4  5  6  7
8  9  10 11
```

to

```
0  3  6  9
1  4  7  10
2  5  8  11
```

?

Try

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
  for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j)
    array_b[ i * height + j ] = array_a[ j * width + i ];
```

Comment: No, I would like the new code to output exactly the same as now. The current code works. I just assume it is slow because I have a mix of row-ordered and column ordered indexing. So I would like to have the row-ordered rewritten to column-order.

Comment: Actually, C typically stores information in row major order (row are stored contiguously).  The most efficient (vis-a-vis, locality of reference) way would be to reorder your column major array to be row major.

Comment: Would it then be possible to rewrite the first to row-ordered? Or am I stuck with the mix?

Comment: There is no better performance you can get from this. You have to touch almost every value in the matrix, so there's no better complexity than O(WxH).

Comment: @Poita_ Big Oh complexity is not the only issue here, a large part of the slowness will probably also be the fact that either the one or the other array will incur a lot of cache misses.

Comment: Cache misses aren't really an issue here, at least for any moderately sized arrays. On the first iteration of the loop, both array_a[0] and array_b[0] will be accessed, causing a whole cache line of each to be stored. If the matrices are very large then yes, cache may be an issue, but there's not really anything you can do about that.

Answer (score 3):

If swapping the row orrdering is common then write your own array class.

The data does not actually have to move just the interface that accesses the data needs to know how to access the data.

```
#include <vector>
class Matrix
{
  public:
    Matrix(int width,int height)
        :data(width,std::vector<int>(height))
        ,rowOrder(true)
    {
    }
    int& operator()(int x,int y)
    {
        return at(x,y);
    }
    int const& operator()(int x,int y) const
    {
        return const_cast<Matrix&>(*this).at(x,y);
    }

    void switchRowOrder()
    {
        rowOrder = !rowOrder;
    }

  private:
    int& at(int x,int y)
    {
        int& result = (rowOrder)
                            ?data[x][y]  // row Order Access
                            :data[y][x]; // col Order Access

        // Note there is no code to swap around the content of the data internally.
        return result;
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<int> >  data;
    bool rowOrder;
};
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the Y-axis flipped, after converting from column-major to row-major.

Comment: I know. I cant do all the work. Given the basic concepts described above a lot of different configurations could be maintained without actually moving the data. You could even plug in policy based access function.

Comment: By time you start adding policies, it's going to start looking a lot like boost::multi_array. ;P (runs away)

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this the cause of your data skew?  All the negative values are being zeroed out:

```
if (d < 0) { d = 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This method (tested with 1D array from 1x1 to 30x30) is working in my case :

```
#include <stdio.h>
void to_col_major(int rows, int cols, int from[rows][cols], int to[rows][cols]) {
    // this method is for 1D array originally...
    int * x = (int *) to, * base = (int *) from, * ptr = base;
    int last_col_index = cols - 1 ;
    int last_index = rows * cols - 1 ;
    int i = -1;
    do {
        int j = i + last_col_index;
        while (i != j) {
            x[++i] = *ptr;
            ptr += rows;
        }
        x[++i] = *ptr;
        ptr = ++base;
    } while (i != last_index);
}

void print_arr(int rows, int cols, int matrix[rows][cols]) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < rows ; ++i, printf("\n"))
        for (int j = 0 ; j < cols ; ++j)
            printf("%4d", matrix[i][j]);
}

int main() {
    int row_major[3][5] = {{1,  2,  3,  4,  5},
                           {6,  7,  8,  9,  10},
                           {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}};
    int col_major[3][5];
    print_arr(3, 5, row_major);
    to_col_major(3, 5, row_major, col_major);
    printf("<- call the function ->\n");
    print_arr(3, 5, col_major);
}

/*
   1   2   3   4   5
   6   7   8   9  10
  11  12  13  14  15

<- call the function ->

   1   4   7  10  13
   2   5   8  11  14
   3   6   9  12  15
*/
```